# here im trying to display a tab, onclicking a button where(list) is a default tab but im getting a masive error saying no overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import CloseableTabs from "react-closeable-tabs";


 interface IState{
            
        data:Array<
            {
                tab?:string,
                component?:string,
                id?:number,
                closable?:boolean,
                         
            } >,     
        activateIndex?:any    
                
};

class App extends React.Component<IState,{}>
{
    
      state = {
        data:[
            {
            tab:"List",
            component:
                    <div><h3>dfgh</h3></div> ,
            id:0,
            closable:false
       },
    ],
        activateIndex:null,   
    };
     addItem = () =>
    {
        let btn = React.createRef()
        const id = new Date().valueOf();
        this.setState({
    data: this.state.data.concat(
        {
            tab:"Compose",
            component: <div><h2>cfvgh</h2></div>,
            id:id,
            closable: true,
        }
    ) ,
        activateIndex: this.state.data.length,
        });
        //this.btn.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    };
    render()
{
    return(
        <div>       
            <button onClick = {this.addItem} >
                Add Item
            </button>
            <CloseableTabs
            tabPanelColor="lightgray"
            data={this.state.data}
            onCloseTab = {(id: number,newIndex: any) =>
            {
                this.setState({
                    data: this.state.data.filter((item) => item.id !== id),
                    activateIndex:newIndex,
                });
            }}
            activateIndex={this.state.activateIndex}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

}
export default App;
```

error:-
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly): App', gave the following error.
Property 'data' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: IState, context?: any): App', gave the following error.
Property 'data' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Readonly'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap `IState` and `{}` in your component declaration:

```js
class App extends React.Component<{}, IState>
```

Props are the first parameter in the `React.Component` type, State is the second. This enables state-less components to omit the second argument.

Comment: Property 'state' in type 'App' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Component<IProps, IState, any>'.